# EXT JS close pop up window

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a pop up window without close button, so I have to refresh the page in order to close the pop up window. In this case, I wanna to add an button on the pop up window for closing.

Here is the js code:

```
function oseGetWIn(id, title, width, height)
{
    var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        id: id,
        name: id,
        title: title,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        closeAction:'destroy',
        autoScroll:'true',

    }); 
    return win; 
}
```

I tried to add the following, but no effect.

```
bbar: [
        {
          text: 'Close',
          handler: function () { this.up('.window').close(); }
         }
      ],
```

Comment: try removing `.` from `this.up('window').close();`

Comment: @MMT Hi, unfortunately, it does not work. am i missing sth?

Comment: where `bbar` is added?, uit snot on window..?

Comment: @MMT, bbar is added under the autoScroll attribute.

Comment: get rid of the id attribute

Answer (score 1):

The selector is incorrect, it should just be `window`, which will find the parent with a matching xtype.

Comment: Hi, seems it does not work when i deleted the dot before window.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'test',
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
            bbar:[{
                text:'Close',
                handler: function(){
                    win.destroy();
                }
            }]
        })
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RdVyz/

Answer (score 1):

hmmm... still not answered?
the solution is simple

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        id: id,
        name: id,
        title: title,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        closeAction:'destroy',
        autoScroll:'true',
        closable:true,
        bbar:[{
            text:'Close',
            handler:function(bt){
                bt.up('window').close();
            }
        }]
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, the exact thing I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    id: id,
    name: id,
    title: title,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    closeAction:'destroy',
    autoScroll:'true',
    closable:true // add this attribute and you will get a close button on right top
});
```

EDIT:
Now try this:

```
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            id: id,
            name: id,
            title: title,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            closeAction:'destroy',
            autoScroll:'true',
            closable:true,
            bbar:[{
                text:'Close',
                handler:function(){
                    this.up('window').destroy();
                }
            }]
        })
```

Comment: What does happan when you click on the Close button? Probably, there are some side errors. Try to trace them looking at firebug.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me the simplest way

```
var wind = Ext.WindowManager.getActive();

if(wind){
     wind.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this
in close handler

this.up().up().close(); 
or
this.up().close();